# Does past simple fits better here

Tags: past-tense, past-simple

I have just heard that he **has/released** a new ep called "bla bla bla"

I think past simple fits better here because first, the release happens, of course ,before I have heard the news of it and it is a single action we are 
 only talking of the new one. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

While both past and perfect are possible, it is natural to use perfect (has released). The release of the ep is a past event with consequences in the present (you knowing about it) You are talking of the present state of the ep, rather than about a past action. We don't care about exactly when it was released. Present perfect is the tense used in this situation.

> I've just heard that he has released ep "bla bla bla"

If you changed to talk about a past time the use the past tense

> I've just heard that he released ep "bla bla bla" yesterday

Comment: but in my mind the release corresponds to a precise moment even if i did not precise the date

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence sounds like it is complete news to you that the ep has been released, like you are surprised. I would use present perfect in that case. If you want to use past tense add when it was released.